# Android: Nougat (Huawei Honor 6x) : Urdu text not displaying correctly

Tags: android, text, urdu

Urdu/Arabic Text is scrambled every where in the operating system ever since I have updated my Huawei Honor 6x from Marshmallow to Nougat. Screenshot is attached. Even when i type the urdu text, incorrect text is typed.

There is no option in the OS to add Arabic language.

What can be the possible solution except downgrading?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the update. Performing a reset again solved the issue.

> Note: Please backup your data before doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow above steps:

1. Download and install GO Keyboard from the Google Play Store
2. Open the app and follow the on-screen steps to enable and switch to GO Keyboard.

Urdu Keyboard on Android Phones

3. After you enable it, go to “Input Settings” in the app and then go to “Input language settings”.
4. Scroll down till you see Urdu (in Urdu font).

Urdu Keyboard on Android Phones

5. Check the box. A popup box will open to download the language files. Tap the ‘Done’ button.

Urdu Keyboard on Android Phones

6. Download “Urdu for GO Keyboard” app from the Android Market.

Urdu Keyboard on Android Phones

7. Now open any app for text input (i.e. Messages) and pop open the keyboard.
8. Tap the ‘EN’ key on your GO Keyboard and it will change to Urdu keyboard.

Urdu Keyboard on Android Phones

I hope this tutorial was helpful to those who want to type in Urdu on Android phones.

GO Keyboard is not the only app which allows you to type in Urdu. MultiLang Keyboard also has Urdu language support.

finally factory reset worked,

{SOLVED} Called huawei support, they suggested the following working solution. After the successful update, if user is facing this language related issue. Again Factory reset should be done wiping Internal Storage as well. (backup should be done before that if necessary) This solved problem.

Comment: This does not solve the problem. As I said even if I receive a correctly sent email or text message or Whatsapp msg. The system does not display Urdu or Arabic text correctly. As you can see the screenshots.

And typing with the help of any keyboard does not solve problem.

![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mtaw9.png)

Comment: Any other thoughts please ?

Comment: {SOLVED}
I dialled huawei support, they suggested the following working solution.

After the successful update, if user is facing this language related issue. Again Factory reset should be done wiping Internal Storage as well. (backup should be done before that if necessary)

This solved my problem. I am unable to ANSWER this question because i am new to S.O.

Comment: yes. it worked. you may paste my solution in Answer. I am unable to answer due to less points. :)